# ASP.NET security provider is stuck storing passwords in plaintext

Tags: asp.net, hash, passwords

I'm writing a small web app for intranet use, which was originally going to use `Windows` authentication.  As such, I set up a few dummy users in `Forms` mode for testing and had the `passwordFormat` set to `Clear` for my own ease of use.

Now, for various reasons, we're not going to use `Windows` authentication anymore (going back to `Forms` authentication and the ASP.NET Membership provider) so I would like to enable password hashing or encryption so the passwords are more secure.  I've changed this in the web.config file, but anytime I create a new user or update an existing user's password, the passwords are still storing in plaintext.  This is happening whether I make these changes through the application (using the built-in management forms) or if I run the provider's stored procedures directly in the database (setting the appropriate `@PasswordFormat` variable, of course).  In other apps where I've left the format on the default of `Hashed`, the hashing takes place automatically, so I'm very perplexed by this behavior.

Is there a way to get this back to hashing the passwords before storing?  Or is this one of those "once you turn it on, you're stuck" kind of situations?

Comment: You should be using a well proven technology such as Microsoft Identity to handle authentication, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it wasn't super clear in my question, but I'm not trying to make my own.  I am using the built-in ASP.NET Membership provider.  I'm sure Identity is overall a better system, but this setup is working in all aspects *except* that it's no longer storing the passwords in hashed format.  I doubt anyone will see them, and the data they are protecting is not super secret.  This is more just in case someone does manage to query the database directly, I don't want everyone's favorite password being visible.